# Trying to update related table with Spring Boot and Thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have `Wallet` and `Transaction` entities. So, when I display to user his wallets, on each wallet he have option for income/expense transaction. When user create a for example income transaction, that transaction is added to `Transaction` page. Now, as I have `update` option for Wallet, so user can update data for Wallet, I want to add user option to update Transaction. I tried to create something but so far it didn't work well. I will show you below down my code and what are responses.

First of all those are two entites that I'm working with on this:

`Wallet:`

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "wallet")
public class Wallet {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "wallet_id")
private Long id;

@NotBlank(message = "Please, insert a wallet name")
private String walletName;

@NotNull(message = "Please, insert a amount")
private Double initialBalance;

@Transient
private double totalBalance;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false, referencedColumnName = "user_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
@OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
@JsonIgnore
private User user;

@Column(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
private Long userId;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "wallet", cascade = {
        CascadeType.ALL})
private Set<Transaction> transactions;
```

`Transaction:`

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "transaction")
public class Transaction {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "transaction_id")
private Long id;

@Column(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
private Long userId;

@Column(name = "wallet_name", nullable = false)
private String walletName;

@NotNull(message = "Please, insert a amount")
@Min(value = 0, message = "Please, insert a positive amount")
private Double amount;

private String note;

@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
@Column(name = "date")
private LocalDate date;

@ManyToOne
@OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.NO_ACTION)
@JoinColumn(name = "wallet_id", nullable = false)
private Wallet wallet;

@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@Column(name = "transaction_type", columnDefinition = "ENUM('EXPENSE', 'INCOME')")
private TransactionType transactionType;

@Nullable
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@Column(name = "expense_categories", columnDefinition = "ENUM('FOOD_AND_DRINK', 'SHOPPING', 'TRANSPORT', 'HOME'," +
        " 'BILLS_AND_FEES', 'ENTERTAINMENT', 'CAR', 'TRAVEL', 'FAMILY_AND_PERSONAL', 'HEALTHCARE'," +
        " 'EDUCATION', 'GROCERIES', 'GIFTS', 'BEAUTY', 'WORK', 'SPORTS_AND_HOBBIES', 'OTHER')")
private ExpenseCategories expenseCategories;

@Nullable
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@Column(name = "income_categories", columnDefinition = "ENUM('SALARY', 'BUSINESS', 'GIFTS', 'EXTRA_INCOME', 'LOAN', 'PARENTAL_LEAVE', 'INSURANCE_PAYOUT', 'OTHER')")
private IncomeCategories incomeCategories;
```

Then I have controller to `update` transaction:

```
@PostMapping("/saveIncome/{walletId}")
public String saveIncome(@PathVariable(value = "walletId") long walletId, @Valid 
@ModelAttribute("transaction") Transaction transaction, BindingResult result, Model model) {

    Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    UserDetailsImpl user = (UserDetailsImpl) authentication.getPrincipal();
    long userId = user.getId();

    Wallet wallet = walletService.getWalletById(walletId);

    boolean thereAreErrors = result.hasErrors();
    if (thereAreErrors) {
        model.addAttribute("incomeCategories", IncomeCategories.values());
        return "income_transaction";
    }

    transaction.setWallet(wallet);
    transaction.setUserId(userId);
    transaction.setWalletName(wallet.getWalletName());
    transactionService.saveIncome(transaction, walletId, userId);
    return "redirect:/api/wallet/userWallet/balance/" + userId;
}
```

And this is `use-case:`

First, I go at `Transaction` page and URL is `http://localhost:8080/api/transaction/userTransactions/1` here `1` stays for `id from user`,
on that page I get listed all user transaction, now, when I click on update button, I get redirected to: `http://localhost:8080/api/transaction/showFormForUpdate/36` where `36` stays for `id from transaction`, and that is fine, also, I get well displayed fields and can change value of them, so actually, I mean, I get correct fields, I get amount populated, note, date, all of that stuff, and I'm ready to update it. So, I change some of values and then, when I click on submit, I get `Whitelabel Error Page` and URL is `http://localhost:8080/api/transaction/saveIncome/` without any `Id` at the end.

What I'm missing? I'm updating `Wallet` on same way and it works fine, but this when I need to update related entity is confusning me, and I dont know what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add something like this, because:

```
model.addAtribute("attribute_name" attribute_name); added to check ther error.

 @PostMapping("/saveIncome/{walletId}")
    public String saveIncome(@PathVariable(value = "walletId") long walletId, @Valid 
    @ModelAttribute("transaction") Transaction transaction, BindingResult result, Model model)
{
// your code here.
   model.addAttribute("transaction", transaction);
    reurn "your/thymeleaf/page";
}
```

Comment: xDDDDDDDDDDDDDD

Comment: You need to add more than one (model.addAttribute) to pass data to thymeleaf page.